# Jquery UI Autocomplete Load on page load

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

i'm trying to load the autocomplete data at the page load, right now it is doing the getJson when i type some letters in the input, and because of the size of the json data, it is freezing. So i want the autocomplete json request to be fired at the loading of the page, and have the data, so when i start typing it wont freeze. Cheers!

```
    <script>
$(function() {

  $.getJSON("airports.php", function(data) {

            $( "#cityAirport" ).autocomplete({
                source: data
            });
        });
});
</script>
```

My Exatc problem is, that right now when i start typing something, the website freezes for a seconds (2-3) when getJson is fired...

Comment: Please explain what the problem is - what do you want help with? The code you are displaying, what is wrong with it?

Comment: Maybe limiting the results would be a good option. You could also generate the data server-side and format it correctly. Then just echo it there.

Comment: @AndersHolmström My Exatc problem is, that right now when i start typing something, the website freezes for a seconds (2-3) when getJson is fired...

Comment: The code example you've shown should avoid that - i.e. getting the JSON data on page load. Isn't it working?

Comment: @AndersHolmström nope :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll make an answer out of this instead of a comment. You can limit it and also use `minLength` to only get the data when you have typed more than * characters.

```
$.getJSON("airports.php", function(data) 
{
    $( "#cityAirport" ).autocomplete(
    {
        source: data,
        max: 10, // Limit the autocomplete options that will show
        minLength: 3 // Will only autocomplete when there are 3 or more letters
    });
});
```

If this doesn't fix it, maybe try fetching less results in the first place.